# Reputation and point system models

Tags: model, points

I'm looking to implement a reputation-based point system for a QA site. I like Stack Overflow's model, but I was wondering if there's anything else like this out there. I was doing some research on the web, but couldn't find a good compiled list of reputation models. If there's a study of reputation models with pros and cons, that would be super valuable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O'Reilly and Associates actually has [a blog](http://buildingreputation.com) and a [book](http://buildingreputation.com/doku.php) coming out about this.

As far as 'systems', there are many:

- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com)
- [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org)
- Digg
- [Wikipedia](http://wikipedia.org) (Implicit with Trusted editors)
- [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com)

Among many, many others.

Answer (score 3):

For a related but different approach, check out http://www.klout.com - they're building a web-wide reputation system that looks at social signals from a growing list of sites.

Answer (score 2):

You can check other sites like this one (expert-exchange) - but I think SO is the best one I've found on the net.